# Error Strpos date array - PHP

Tags: php

Good afternoon , I have to look for an array if there is a word or not, but does not display anything . Can help me solve ?

```
$query110 = "SELECT * FROM tbl_pacientes_agendamento
             WHERE id_consultorio='".$_GET['consultorio']."' AND id_medico='".$_GET['medico']."'";
$result110 = mysql_query($query110);
while($fetch110 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result110)){
    $conta_array = $conta_array + 1;
    $array_horario[] = $fetch110['horario'];
    $array_data[] = $fetch110['data'];
}

$range = range(strtotime($horario_inicio_aux), strtotime($horario_fim_aux), $fetch11['tempo_consulta'] * 60);
foreach($range as $time){
    $string1011 = date("H:i",$time);
    if(strpos($string1011, $array_horario) !== false) {
        echo '';
    } else {
        echo '<a href="confirma_marcacao.php?consultorio='.$_GET['consultorio'].'&medico='.$_GET['medico'].'&especialidade='.$_GET['especialidade'].'&horario='.date("H:i",$time).'&dia_semana='.$dia_string.'&data='.$data.'" class="btn btn-day">'.date("H:i",$time).'</a>';
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `strpos` doesn't return `true` or `false`, it returns the position. Use `if (strpos(...) !== false)`. This is explained in the manual.

Comment: even with the above syntax did not work :(

Comment: I remove the variavle $string1011="0" too, but dont work yet

Comment: You should read this first. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php If there is a reason to use the very old PHP, add proper tags and describe it too.

Comment: but the error is in the array? When I give a pre he displays certain

Comment: Solved... I replace strpos to array_search... works fine, Thanks.